# Can you wirelessly sync a Windows 7 phone (HTC Trophy) without leaving it plugged in to charge for 15 mins?

Tags: wireless-networking, sync, windows-phone, zune-software, cellular

The only way I know of to sync my HTC Trophy wirelessly is to plug it in to the wall to charge, after which it will automatically sync after X number of minutes.  However, most of the time I want to sync my phone without having to search for my USB cable.  I certainly don't feel like plugging it into the wall and waiting for time to pass before it syncs on its own.

The ideal solution is to be able to access a sync menu, touch "sync now", and have all my pics and vids be transferred to my PC.  I wouldn't have to grab a USB cable or plug it into a wall outlet.

This this possible?

Comment: To sync, your battery must be at least half-charged and connected to an AC power adapter. Have you checked the battery level before waiting these 15 minutes?

Comment: In my opinion, if it has enough power to turn on, browse the web, and take pictures and video, it should have enough power to sync wirelessly without me having to plug it in to anything.

Comment: Try to fully charge it, then see if it still takes 15 mins to sync.

Comment: But if I am going to fully charge it, I may as well just plug it into my PC and sync it via USB while I charge it.

Comment: You can, but that won't help us find the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this **without a custom hack**

<sub>I didn't see a hack on xda-developers ... sorry</sub>

---

From [Microsoft's Windows Phone 7 Syncing Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/music/sync-files-with-my-phone.aspx) >>>

... files will automatically sync with your phone wirelessly when the following conditions are met:

- Your phone and PC are both connected to your home Wi-Fi network. Note that wireless sync is not supported on workplace Wi-Fi networks.
- Your phone battery has at least a medium-level charge *and your phone is connected to an AC power adapter (that is, your phone must be connected to the wall charger and not connected to your computer)*.
- You're not interacting with your phone. For example, you're not touching things on the screen, the backlight is off, and music and videos aren't playing (it's OK if a song or video is paused).

It might take up to 15 minutes for wireless sync to start, and **there is no way to manually force it to occur.**

Comment: Man, that's some really disappointing design implementation.  I am sure Microsoft had a legitimate reason to do it that way and I'd love to hear someone explain it to me.  Anyway, you answered the question I asked, so you get the bounty!